# 403 Forbidden, access denied, when embedding iframe in Moodle

Tags: moodle, server-error

I'm facing with an annoying issue and I tried to solve in various ways. However, I'm still having the issue.
I've installed an LMS (moodle) in a subdomain of my website: https://lms.rafiee.net
I've enabled "Allow EMBED and OBJECT tags" and "Enable trusted content" in moodle setting. However, I'm still getting 403 Forbidden on server side issue when trying to embed a google slide (iframe) in my courses.
When I embed google slide iframe, I can see it, however, when I press save button, it directs me to https://lms.rafiee.net/course/modedit.php

Answer (score 0):

I disabled modesecurity in cpanel and it solved the issue.

Comment: What do you need modsecurity for? If you used something and you don't know what it was for then it is definitely a huge security red flag.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for your reply. i just need it to make sure if it operate as extra security layer.
I don't know how to find which security mode is triggered. Is there any way to find it in shared hosting ?

Comment: I think you mean modSecurity, not **mode**security. There are no modes. You can search online to find the documentation and read what the mod does.